Nextcloud Deck and Python
I try to extend the python Library nextcloud-deck. There is one thing missing in this library I really want to access. And that's the assigned users on the card. I already extended the modle in hope to be able to parse the JSON into the existing Class, but so far I don't get it how to realize it.
@attr.s(auto_attribs=True, frozen=True)
class User:
    primary_key: str
    uid: str
    displayname: str
    type: int

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True, frozen=True)
class Assignment:
    card_id: int
    id: int
    participant: User
    type: int

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True, frozen=True)
class Card:
    id: int
    title: str
    stack_id: int
    last_modified: int
    created_at: int
    owner: str
    order: int
    archived: bool
    assignedUsers: typing.List[str] = attr.Factory(list)
    notified: bool = False
    deleted_at: int = 0
    duedate: typing.Optional[str] = None
    description: typing.Optional[str] = None
    type: str = "plain"
    labels: typing.Optional[typing.List[Label]] = attr.Factory(list)

I tried several different things to geht the assignedUsers into the class. I've added the class user and Assignment. And the field assignedUsers. Doesn't matter what I tried the field stays empty. Even if there is some information in JSON about the assignedUsers.
The JSON I try to parse is this one
{
    "id": 37,
    "title": "Title",
    "description": "",
    "stackId": 8,
    "type": "plain",
    "lastModified": 1712608194,
    "lastEditor": null,
    "createdAt": 1705467293,
    "labels": [],
    "assignedUsers": [
        {
            "id": 20,
            "participant": {
                "primaryKey": "Name",
                "uid": "Name",
                "displayname": "ShortName",
                "type": 0
            },
            "cardId": 37,
            "type": 0
        }
    ],
    "attachments": [],
    "attachmentCount": 0,
    "owner": {
        "primaryKey": "Name2",
        "uid": "Name2",
        "displayname": "ShortName2",
        "type": 0
    },
    "order": 0,
    "archived": false,
    "duedate": "2024-01-30T23:00:00+00:00",
    "deletedAt": 0,
    "commentsUnread": 0,
    "commentsCount": 0,
    "ETag": "8432d5e8466347d6d16f5869ad92d20b",
    "overdue": 3
}

For me it seams like the assignedUsers is a list of dict. But I have no idea how to put this together.
Would be great if someone could give me a hint. Thanks a lot.
Or even better if there is already a lib that returns the assignedUsers from the Nextcloud card.
PS: That would be the docs of the api https://deck.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/
I tried to changed to bold code above to make my issue work.

Chagned the text. Seams like it's not possible to mark code as Bold.
